# System crashed but no autosave file found

Tags: blend-files, linux

I had been working on a Blender file for about an hour when my whole system just crashed and powered itself off (using Ubuntu 13.10, and I had many applications open).

The /tmp directory where the autosave file is typically found had no blender files in it.

I just opened Blender again and confirmed that the autosave feature is working properly according to my settings (saving 2734.blend every 3 minutes).

So why is there no autosave file?  The /tmp directory had other files in it, so I don't think that Ubuntu crashing caused the file to be deleted.

Comment: I have had the same problem when blender crashes running ubuntu 13.4

Comment: Did you have to reboot the system? The /tmp directory is usually stored in RAM, which means that everything in it will be lost when the machine restarts.

Comment: Yes, the system powered itself off during the crash.  I edited my answer to reflect that.

Comment: @Garry In that case the reason why the file is missing is because it was lost when the computer turned off. :/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems `/tmp` [is cleared on startup in ubuntu by default](https://askubuntu.com/q/20783/183331), so
unfortunately if you had to reboot your machine everything in `/tmp` was erased.
The other files you saw in `/tmp` were probably created on startup.

Blender has some other backup systems (see this [post](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/3026/599)), but if you did not make any manual saves I'm afraid there is nothing to be done.

## Autosaving to the hard drive:

You could change the directory blender uses to store temporary backups to a location on your hard drive by changing the *Temp* location in <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>U</kbd>*> User preferences > File*:

[image: User preferences screenshot]

Note that this setting controls the location of everything blender puts in `/tmp` by default, not just the autosave files.

Comment: Great, thanks @gandalf3!  Changing the Temp directory worked, which I confirmed forcing my computer to power off.  But I don't believe that /tmp is held in RAM judging by this [page](http://askubuntu.com/questions/173094/how-can-i-use-ram-storage-for-the-tmp-directory-and-how-to-set-a-maximum-amount).

Comment: Also, building off the answer @gandalf3 gave above, an alternative (but not necessarily better) solution is to change the frequency with which /tmp is cleared by following Max's answer [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/20783/how-is-the-tmp-directory-cleaned-up).

Comment: @Garry It can be, but it does seem that you are right that it is not in RAM by default on ubuntu.