# Is it possible to restore a project that I didn't save?

Tags: edit-mode, blend-files

I created a blender model using blender and exported it as an .obj.
I the clicked File > Open and opened a Blender project.
My project before was gone. Is is possible to get it back. I didn't save it as a .blend.

*I can open the obj but it doesn't have the correct edit points*

Comment: Related - http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/14413/how-to-setup-auto-save. However only first way applies to your situation. If you were working on project for some time there should be file with some random number name in temp directory. Try filtering by save time.

Comment: Also see - https://www.blender.org/manual/troubleshooting/recover.html. Keep in mind that Blender probably didn't dave session on qutting because you didn't *close* program, you opened another file.