# Disable Blender autosaving files

Tags: customization, blend-files

It seems that Blender is auto saving my projects, because when I exit Blender and go to my .blendfile again my latest progress (even the ones I did not save nor want to save) were present.

Is there some kind of setting I accidentally changed?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: if you are asking how to disable autosave , do the opposite of this answer : [How to setup Auto Save](http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/14463/2816)

Answer (score 4):

Are you talking about auto save or do you mean that when Blender opens up it automatically opens your last saved project?

Anyway go to *File Menu > User Preferences > File Tab > Auto Save:* on the bottom right

Disable either *Auto Save Temporary Files*, reduce the number of files, or disable *Keep session* if when Blender opens up for the first time it automatically brings up the last opened file.

Keep session doesn't really save the changes to you actual work file however, as far as I know the session is saved to an internal Blender file in the user folder in the last state it was before closing. The actual work file in its directory however should be unchanged and hold only the changes up until the last explicit user save.

Beware that some addons do an automatic save of the file on export (like Blend4Web for example) even if you don't save the file, on export it automatically saves any changes without warning the user or specific user consent, resulting in unwanted and unforeseen file saves. If you are using any addons check in it's preferences if there is such setting as 'auto-save'

Comment: Hi thanks for the response. Where do I find the preferences for the addons?

Comment: Depends on the addon, some are right in the *User Preferences > Addons* in the addon entry itself. For export addons (like Blend4Web) some export related settings show up in the export dialog right in file browser's Tool Shelf on the bottom left while exporting. Other addons may have the preferences directly in the addon UI integrated in the Blender UI though those are unlikely to auto-save your file.