# Texture Atlas issues

Tags: uv

Okay, so I started a manual unwrap on a model, did a lot of work marking seams, placing UV islands, scaling them, etc, etc. Blender crashed and I lost the work. I took a break, went  back to it, got up to the same point and instantly saved *curse you blender and your naff session recovery*.

Now that I've got my UV all set up and where I want it, I ended my manual unwrap, and it moved all the UV's as if they were fresh Unwraps, taking up the entire UV space for each object. Am I missing something?

For me it's: Select all the objects to unwrap, start manual unwrap, do the business and all that with UV space, come out of edit mode, end manual unwrap. Is that right? If so, what's going on with this unwrapping? Pictures to follow.
[image: Perfect UV]

[image: What]

Comment: The top is my laid out UV, the bottom is the result of finishing my manual unwrap

Comment: do the individual objects possibly have more than one uv map?

Comment: I don't believe so. I literally made the object, then went straight into manual unwrap. There wasn't a chance for me to generate a UV out of it. If that somehow is the case though, how do I rectify that?

Comment: Check the mesh data tab in the properties editor, section uv maps. How many do you see? And which one is active?

Comment: Hmmm there are indeed two, although I have no idea how that happened with only that part and not the others as well. So, if I remove the UV map in the second screenshot, it should use the new UV I used in my manual unwrap?

Comment: You can have up to 8 UV maps per mesh in Blender at the moment. The one with the render icon activated is the one which is passed on to the UV output socket in a node tree. But for now, let's not overcomplicate things, so yes, remove the one you don't need, and the Texture Atlas one should remain and work as expected.

Comment: By the way, here are some ways that might save more work than recovering the last session: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/14463/31893

Comment: Okay so, I removed the old UV and decided it was better off to mirror the object, seeing as it was largely symmetrical anyway. I proceeded to unwrap as per normal in texture atlas, got my final result, went to finish my manual unwrap and now two of my objects are split up into thousands of triangles all occupying the majority of the UV space....I am so very confused right now. Pictures, again, to follow.

Comment: you have removed the uvs from all source objects before beginning the Texture Atlas unwrap I suppose? How about uploading the file to http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com

Answer (score 1):

### Check if you have more than one UV Map on the object

If your object already had a UV Map for some reason, TextureAtlas will simply create another UV map. In Blender, per mesh object, at the moment up to 8 different UV maps per mesh are supported. You can see a list of your UV maps in the mesh data tab of your object:

[image: UV mesh data tab]

As you can see, by simply clicking at the names, you can switch from one map to the other. The render icon at the right determines which UV map gets passed on to the Texture Coordinates node in the Node Editor:

[image: TexCoords node]

If the TextureAtlas UV map is all you need, just remove all other maps using the <kbd>-</kbd> Button.