# Cannot Save Blend File Says, "Cannot open file filename.blend@ for writing: Too many open files"

Tags: export, blend-files

Today I saw something in Blender I've never seen before. It says, "Cannot open file filename.blend@ for writing: Too many open files".

[image]

Which I'm confused on. It's the only Blender project open. I pressed the close button on the window and it didn't close. I spent 2 hours trying to find a solution online and couldn't find anything.

Does anyone know why this is and how to resolve it?

If anyone can help it'll be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you saving in a shared folder? Is the file open in different instances of blender or different computers? Do you have write privileges for the folder where you want to write? Is the file protected for writing or locked?

Comment: Nope, I'm saving in my Downloads folder and I have admin privileges.

Comment: Is the file locked?

Comment: Nope it's not locked

Comment: Looks similar to this https://blenderartists.org/t/2-66-rendering-sequence-fails-too-many-open-files/572576. Doesn't seem to have solutions as it wasn't widespread and easy to reproduce. It could be not enough free RAM though in this case often there is another error. Did you try Save As command to save into new file? Do you run recent version of Blender? Also note there is saving backups system in Blender (if it's enabled) which saves copies of the file to /temp directory

Comment: I tried Save as and am running the most recent current stable version of Blender

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I had no choice but to force close Blender and lost hours of productive work because of this problem.

I still have no idea as to how this problem even occurred but a good reminder to always save your work constantly. Otherwise, you'll lose hours of productive time.

Comment: Learn how to set auto save: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/14413/how-to-setup-auto-save