# How to recover unsaved file or abort endless operation?

Tags: modifiers, objects, edit-mode

I accidentally and essentially crashed Blender during a build I was doing for a friend.

I added a Subsurface modifier to an object I was creating so I could see where to add extra loops. However, when I went to type in "6" for the views, I accidentally typed "65".

I don't know if Blender can handle this request, but I'm going to leave the system running for a while (I hadn't saved the file yet, so I'll lose a couple hours of puttering around if I force it to close). It seems to be trying to process the request, as it's running more memory than anything I've ever seen and knew was possible with my computer (I just saw it go over 27 Gb on the RAM, CPU running a lot power right now too, and my hard drive seems to be at its limit for data transfer).

Now I imagine I am not the first person to encounter this problem with Blender, but I wanted to ask if there is a way to recover a file that hasn't been saved recently if the system crashes? Or if there is a way to abort operation which is being calculated for too long?

Comment: Blender has built-in recovery system which saves file in temp directory and it should auto save before complex computations, see https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/14413/how-to-setup-auto-save; however it should have already been enabled for this to work. Note that this site is not for feature requests, see https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1190/best-place-to-put-feature-requests

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a feature request

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to setup Auto Save?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/14413/how-to-setup-auto-save)

Comment: The subsurface modifier maxes out at eleven.