# Replacing the "recover last session" button with a "recover auto save..." button

Tags: interface

Okay, so not long ago, I experienced a crash with blender that made me lose serious progress on something I was working on.
When I booted up Blender again in a bit of what was a mix of frustration and panic, I noticed the "recover last session" button on the splash screen. Having very little experiences with crashes prior to this incident, this attractive little button made me think that this would recover my last auto save, when in fact it did NOT do such, and by the time I figured out how to actually recover my last auto save, it was too late as my auto save was written over by then, with this misleading button being a good chunk of why.

**What I want to do is get rid of this button**, as I feel it's a completely pointless button (If I'm not mistaken, clicking the top file in the "recent" column does literally the same thing), **and replace it with the "recover auto save..." function that can be found in the "file" drop down menu**, something that would have actually helped me in my time of need. 
I feel it should be mentioned that I have no experience in interface editing, so I honestly don't know if this is something that's even possible to do. Additionally, if it helps, I am using the 2.75 version of Blender.

Comment: Also I apologize if this question is poorly formatted; between me still being tilted over this, being extreme tired, and still being rather new to stack exchange, it's possible that, despite the fact it looks fine to me, that it could be anything but

Comment: *"clicking the top file in the "recent" column does literally the same thing"* no it doesn't. Files in the "Recent" category are ones saved on disk and opened recently. You are mixing 2 different functions, Recover Auto Save and Recover Last Session do different things, albeit similar. See https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/14413/how-to-setup-auto-save. Note also so far your question is more a feature-request which is off-topic on this site, you could [edit] it

Comment: @MrZak I am fully aware that "recover auto save..." and "recover last session" are different, which, as per my question, was what screwed me over. Additionally, I really don't know how this came off as a feature request to you, as what I'm asking in this is **not** for Blender to change this (I honestly don't care if the Blender dev team changes this or not), but rather how **I** can change Blender to my preferences.