# ! Going Back in Blender Project History?

Tags: blend-files, saving

I think I may have lost a lot of my work but I'm hoping someone here can help me find a way to recover it.

I'm working on an animation project where when I make a new scene I usually make a copy of one of my existing scenes that has the models I created already in it and use it as a template for the new scene so that I don't have to recreate or append my models.

I usually take an existing scene, make a copy using "Save As" with a new file name for the new scene and then delete all the previous keyframes to get a clean slate, but still have all my models.

However, in my most recent session, I realized that I had actually forgotten to first make a copy of my original scene by using Save As and so had just deleted my original project, which represented a lot of work. I'm been looking around to see if there is a way to go back to my original file or go back in my project history so I can restore my original file but can't find a way to do this.

Is there a way to see my Blender projects history? I just need to be able to go back to the original file before I made all my changes. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 5):

You may have an autosave of when you last quit, you can check in this menu.

[image]

Comment: @blasterfish Or try to check .blend1 file https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/14463/2214

Comment: Oh this is true.  I've disabled this because I can go back file versions in a lot of cases.