# Blender Autosave has failed to load

Tags: blend-files

In blender, I have not saved the file because Blender crashed. So, I restart my computer and I open Blender again and go to "Recover Auto Save". I choose my file, however, it says that it fails to read that .blend file, and all I see on the screen is a blank cube. Why is this so?

Comment: Related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/5222/599. What operating system are you on?

Comment: I am on a Windows. The autosave thing has worked fine before, but now it is not working.

Comment: It sounds as if the auto-saved file was corrupted in some way. Does it at least have a non-0 size?

Comment: What is a non-0 size?

Comment: I mean, what is shown under the file size column when viewing the auto-saved .blend in either the windows file explorer or blender's file browser?

Comment: Yes, it has a non-0 size

Comment: Could you [upload it](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/)?

Comment: How can I upload it to here?

Comment: See https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/q/658/599 or the link in my previous comment

Comment: I can't do that because my file is not saved.

Comment: I mean the corrupted auto-save

Comment: How do we upload the corrupted file, which folder is it in?

Comment: IIRC it goes in `C:\Temp` or something like that, but you should be able to see what directory blender opens its filebrowser to when you do "Recover Auto Save".

Comment: I can see the directory but it does not show the same when I open file explorer.