# How can I undo Edit steps in Object Mode?

Tags: objects, edit-mode

From time to time I lose all edits because of undo in Object Mode. If I enter immediately after Undo in Edit Mode I can't redo, and switching again in Object results in losing all edit history.

### How can I resolve this? Separating undo history by mode or linear/unified will both be acceptable.

Edit:I think the most preferable solution will be to disable/skip **edit undos** when in **object mode** through an addon.

Comment: related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/3026/599

Answer (score 6):

This is just the way the undo system works currently. There has been some discussion about this lately, mainly due to [this video](http://www.blenderguru.com/fixing-blender-part-2-going-deeper/) (the part relevant to undo is at `8:12`)

The trick when this happens is to redo in *object mode* immediately after undoing all your edit mode changes:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

This seems like a pretty bad situation but can also work to your advantage once you are accustomed to it.

If you use Undo in Object mode, then you can use Redo before re-entering Edit mode to prevent the loss of what you've done.

There reason I say this can be a good thing is because you can bypass the maximum number of Undo's available to edit by entering Object mode then pressing Undo.

Also, this can save you a lot of Undo's in Edit mode if you know that you want to discard all the many small changes that you have recently made.

What is common to all DCC apps is the save button.  Use it often and if you use <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> then press the <kbd>+</kbd> on the NUMPAD, you will have a saved version that has an increment which is one higher then the previous saved version so you will now have 2 .blends and the second will have a 1 at the end of the name.  Do this again and you will have another with a 2 appended to the name.

Answer (score 2):

This... is really terrible. I can foresee that until you have trained yourself to be aware of this problem, it would be very easy to inadvertently destroy all your work: accidentally enter object mode, hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> to revert your mesh to its original state, then change something in the scene which destroys the redo history.

Not that that just happened to me...

Comment: Yay, as of Blender 2.8 it looks like this doesn't happen anymore!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get back my undo function in Blender 2.78c by ticking the option "Global undo" in the "Editing" category in User Preferences. That solved it for me, as I must have disabled it by mistake.