# How to recover overwritten files in blender

Tags: workflow, blend-files

I had just finished creating a realistic human head in blender that took me about four hours to make. I then tried to open it in a new file but I accidentally saved over it.

Someone please help, I'm really upset about losing all that time and effort.

Comment: Related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/3026/599

Answer (score 14):

There are several backup systems in blender:

## Temporary files (saved every 2 minutes by default)

These will be saved in your temporary directory (specified in *User preferences > File*) with a random number as the name.

You can quickly open an auto saved file by pressing *File > Recover auto save*, then selecting the auto saved file (the modification times can be very useful for determining which file to pick):

[image]

You can adjust the interval at which these are saved in <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>U</kbd> *User preferences > File > Auto save > Timer*:

[image]

## Temporary quit files (saved on quit)

These are also saved in your temporary directory, with the name `quit.blend`.
You can quickly open it one by pressing *File > Recover last session*:

[image]

## Persistent save files for reverting accidental/unwanted saves (saved when saving)

These are saved as `.blend1`, `.blend2`, etc. files in the same directory as the current .blend.
.blend1 will be the file as it was the save before your last save, .blend2 will be the save before the save before your last save, etc.

To open these files, navigate to the directory where your file was saved and enable backup files in the display filter:

[image]

You can configure the number of these to save in *User preferences > File*:

[image]

---

Without knowing more about your particular situation (how long it's been, has tmp been cleared, how often did you save, etc.), it's hard to say which will work best. There's no risk to trying them all, be beware that `/tmp` or `\Temp` is normally cleared out at some point, so get any useful backups out while you can.

Answer (score 1):

For version 3.1+

You may read [3 Ways to Recover Lost Work](https://www.blenderguru.com/tutorials/3-ways-recover-lost-work), the section *Case 2: You Save Over the Wrong File*.

The principle is each time you save a file using an existing file name, prior to overwriting it the current content is copied into another file which extension is .blend1. when .blend1 already exists its content is first saved to .blend2, etc. So at any time your disk contains a file with data last saved, and a few previous versions. You can open any of these files. In your case use the .blend1 version as the file was overwritten only once.

You may display .blend1, .blend2, etc files by setting the Open File *filter*:

[image]

How many copies are kept on the disk is set in the preferences:

[image]

The default value is 1. Note also there is a setting to prevent files to be filtered (that is to show only .blend extensions) in the Open dialog.

Answer (score 0):

Every time you save, blender will create a save file in the same location of the file, with (.blend1) as the file type instead of (.blend)

if you havn't saved yet on the new file, then this (.blend1) save file will still have the content of the overwritten lost file, you can tell by if they have a size difference.

if this is so, then delete the (.blend file) of the new file, and change the (.blend1) files name to be (.blend) this will restore the file.