# How to load older versions of a blend file?

Tags: workflow, blend-files

Is it possible to load earlier versions of a project? I generally use the same project for the same type of occasion and in an earlier save I had something that I wanted to use again.

Is it possible for me to load older project saves?

Answer (score 1):

By default blender will save 2 old versions whenever you save the blend file. That feature is what makes the `.blend1` `.blend2` flies. Read the bottom of gandalf3's answer [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/14103/2217), for more info on the persistent save feature. The `.blend1` will be in the same folder as the blend file it is a backup of.

However if you do not have a backup blend, there is now way in blender to get back to a edit that has been saved over.