# My roblox model and character are not showing

Tags: modeling

I install the blender and open it, work on a model and forget to save and closed the blender. I reopen the blender now my model and character are not showing in blender than I reinstall the blender than also my model are not showing , when  I open my blender a cube is showing but my model and character are not showing

Comment: Is the file empty? Have you checked all the layers? What happened, when you lost your models?

Comment: [Related](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/14101/how-to-recover-overwritten-files-in-blender) and [Related 2](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/21166/how-to-load-older-versions-of-a-blend-file)

Comment: Sorry to be the one to bring you the bad news, but if you did not save your file your work is gone. Reinstalling blender will not change that. What you are seeing now is the default scene.

Comment: @David They would have a quit.blend, and possibly an autosave lying around still (related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/3026/599)

Answer (score 1):

Try all these possibilities:

1. Check all the layers
2. Try pressing the "/" division key
3. Try Pressing Alt + H key - HIDE/SHOW Feature
4. Hit "A" key twice and the press "." (Period key) - OUT OF FOCUS ISSUE