# Create a cycles material from rendered picture

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, materials, light

I managed to delete a really neat blender file, and the only thing left is this rendered picture, which I made off the file before deleting it:
[image]

I **REALLY** loved the colors, materials and lighting, and ever since I deleted the file, I have been trying to recreate the materials on the floor and cube. I managed to dig up an older auto-save file, with the right objects (without the light sources or materials) and ever since I have attempted to recreate this, now I've pulled off every material BUT the glossy purple floor! I have a vague idea that I used a Mix shader, but I simply can't make it right. What bothers me most is the reflection of the light source in the original, compared to the one I have tried:
[image: comparison render]

*How did I pull off such a sharp edge, while still keeping some blurriness? I have no idea whatsoever.*

How do I recreate the material for the floor?

If you wanna see for yourself, here's where you can download the file [right here](http://www.pasteall.org/blend/35112)

Comment: In the file menu select recover autosave, check there if you can find the older version

Comment: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/14413/how-to-setup-auto-save

Comment: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/14101/how-to-recover-overwritten-files-in-blender

Answer (score 2):

Something like this?
[image: comparaison add!]
Or with mix nodes
[image: comparaison mix!]
I moved your light meshes a bit to fit the ref image and also changed the background from 2 to 1 to get darker shadows.
[image]

Comment: wow thanks man! I still gotta get used to making complex materials while knowing what i'm doing, sometimes I forget im still a newbie... Anyway thanks for your time!

Comment: Also, how did you make the camera perspective only render inside the camra view?

Comment: From camera view (0) use Shift+B. From anywhere, use Ctrl+B. Have fun :)