# Blender file keeps crashing - how do I open it in safe mode?

Tags: command-line

I'm making a blender video using the VSE and compositor, with multiple scenes. I noticed that it's a bit buggy when I'm using blender scenes in the VSE editor, but so far everything was working.

Now all of sudden, I can't even open the blender file without it crashing. Please help! Is there a way to run it in safe mode, or disable something so that it will open?

I'm on a macbook pro running blender 2.76b. I don't know how to view the console so I can see the error message.

Comment: You may be out of luck for that particular file. It might be time to start trying the [various backup files saved automatically](http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/14101/599). If possible, you might consider [filing a bug report](http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/1377/599) (with the corrupted file) so the devs can find out what happened and prevent it from happening in the future.

Answer (score 3):

You can find the terminal in Applications/Utilities and you can start blender by typing the following into a terminal window (this is the default so you may have to adjust folder names if you have altered them)

```
/Applications/Blender/blender.app/Contents/MacOS/blender
```

This may only give a simple message like *Segmentation Fault*

A few things you may want to try -

- Turn off *Load UI* when opening the blend file - this will leave you in the default screen layout and not take you straight into the VSE where you where last time.
- Turn off *Trusted Source* when opening the blend file - this will only help if you have drivers/scripts setup to run automatically
- Use *File->Load Factory settings* before opening the blend file - this will disable non-default addons that may be causing an issue.
- Also turn off *Load UI* and *Trusted Source* after loading factory defaults.
- Start with a new file and import objects/animations from the bad file.

Comment: Thanks. I will give those methods a try. And good point about starting a new blend file and importing the objects. That didn't even occur to me!

and sambler, you are correct - I started the Terminal window and it gave me this error:

"Writing: /tmp/30_Second_Political_Ad_Template.crash.txt
Segmentation fault: 11"

Comment: sambler - I turned off Load UI like you suggested and damned if it didn't open. Thank you thank you!!!

Answer (score 0):

So I'm still not quite sure what was causing the original blend file to crash on startup, but I have a few suspicions. I think there's a bug with the VSE editor when importing blender scenes, as opposed to outside clips.

Blender must assume that the 3D scenes have to be rendered first, in order to display them in the edit layout. And because I had one scene that was composited overtop the other, it might have been too much calculation work that Blender was forced to do and crashed.

When I disabled "Load UI" in preferences, the default layout opened no problem, which leads me to believe the error occurs in the VSE only. I also think the fact I was using the compositor to tweak the colours for the 3D scenes, before they were imported into the final VSE scene might have been too much of a memory hog.

I will of course submit the file to developers to see if they can further isolate the error.