# Why are some of my objects missing?

Tags: linked-data

I tried to link object data when creating a new scene so that I could render an explosion exclusively with the same nodes as the original scene.  Then in the new scene, I deleted all the objects from the first scene that I didn't need.  I saved the file and closed it.  Now when I opened it again and looked at the first scene, all of my objects were gone!  They must be somewhere though because the file is 198mb.

I've worked on this for weeks...is there any solution??

Comment: If they are not in the "Outliner" then they are gone. If they are in the "Outliner"with your mouse in the 3D Viewport try pressing ALT + H to unhide them. Also make sure the layer they are on is active. Try to find an Auto Saved file and open that? In addition, always make incremental copies of your project as you work on it.

Comment: You could recover undesired changes - http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/14101/how-to-recover-overwritten-files-in-blender. Check in Blender temp directory (to find where it is open User Preferences > File).

Comment: @Dontwalk thanks for those tips...unfortunately the objects weren't in the outliner and ALT+H didn't work.  The layer was active.

Comment: @MrZak that was a helpful article.  Again, unfortunately I was unable to find a recent version that was saved in the temp folder.  For some reason just the current file and .quit file, which is the same.  All the others .Blend files were other projects.  I thought it would have autosaved several versions.

Comment: Are the object moved to another layer by accident? If it's 198mb file , it's probably still there.

Comment: Have you tried searching in the outliner?  Also make sure the Outliner is set to see All Scenes?

Comment: @hawkenfox no I checked.  It's really strange.

Comment: @MikeBelanger Yeah I checked the outliner.  They weren't in there either.  I managed to start all over again and append all the objects I made in earlier files (it's a video I'm trying to make with other objects) but it's frustrating that I can't figure out why the file is so huge if there are apparently no objects (except for a few cubes I cell fragmented).