# Is it possible to recover deleted files in the file browser?

Tags: file-browser

I just spent a month rendering an animation, and in the process of importing all the images into the sequencer, I accidentally deleted all of them.

Oops.

I still have Blender open; is it possible to recover them? Were they moved to a temporary directory somewhere to be deleted later? Despite being several gigabytes of data, the images disappeared instantly, leading me to believe that they're not truly deleted, just moved.

Comment: Do not write anything else on that drive! Use some file recovery software (there are tons of them, a lot of them open source).

Comment: Did you check the Recxyle Bin?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## No.

Sorry :/
Blender only really has mechanisms for [recovering blendfiles](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/14101/599).

## But wait..

Deleting files is likely fast because usually files are deleted by flipping a single bit which indicates to the operating system that this space is now available for use. The data is still there, but the longer you use the system the more likely it is some other program will overwrite it.

If you can, **unmount/eject the drive until you can mount it read-only**. If the disk in question is the one the OS is on, shut down the system and use a [livecd](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Live_CD) (or an OS on another disk) to mount it (read-only, of course).

It's probable that can you can at least recover some of the files (possibly all) using conventional undelete methods such as [photorec](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec). How exactly to do this will depend on the format of filesystem your drive has, among other things. I recommend searching around for instructions for your specific operating system/filesystem.

Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

I just had this happen to me by accident and my heart stopped for a little bit, file explorer doesn't have a "undo delete" on the options tab.

But by my full surprised and relieve to find out that when I accidentally deleted my files, it doesn't disappear entirely, but it just go straight to the *Recycle Bin* on Windows (which is why it deletes it instantly), so I just selected all the files I accidentally deleted and my day is blessed.