# I can not disable the Fracture tool add-on?

Tags: add-on

I added the fracture tool and my cup transformed into a square (formed from more inequal faces) and now, because I saved, closed and opened the project again (so ctrl+z doesn't work anymore) I can not disable the add-on and return to my cup. I also checked if the previous version was automatically saved, but it wasn't. Can someone help me?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to recover overwritten files in blender](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/14101/how-to-recover-overwritten-files-in-blender)

Comment: Never use Save always us Save As and click the + by the Save button to create a incremental name. Good luck recovering your work using the link above.