# cant restore previous version of file

Tags: blend-files

i accidently saved over an important blender file and don't know how to recover it I have already looked it up and cant find anything, if you know how to recover blender files then please tell me

Comment: hi and welcome, does this answer your question? - https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/14101/how-to-recover-overwritten-files-in-blender

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to do this. go to > file> recover> recover>last session.

[image: recover last session]

this should work to recover your last saved file.

Comment: *Recover last session* doesn't recover the last session at all. It recovers the status of Blender data when the program was closed (not crashed). So in the OP case it will just reload the new version of the file. What the OP wants is to recover data that were overwritten, this is possible because Blender saves a copy of existing data before overwriting them. This file has an extension .blend1, [just open it](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/263409/15265).