# .blend1 File Function

Tags: blend-files

What does the .blend1 file do?
It automatically appears every time you create a .blend file.
I only use the .blend file.
When I double-click on the .blend file, it opens Blender.
When I double-click on the .blend1 file, it doesn't have a software to run the file.
What is the .blend1 file used for?

Comment: These are backup files of the previous save. Some related questions: http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/14413/599, http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/14101/599, and http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/3026/599