# How do i animate a group rotating as one object?

Tags: animation

When i tryied to animate a group rotating (2 rotation keyframes), all of the objects rotated at thier pivot points insted of the "whole group" pivot point. How do i make the whole group rotate as one object?

Here i've recoreded a gif of my problem. [GIF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ugvFC.jpg)

Comment: Are they all grouped together as one object or are they all parented to one object? I would try joining all of them with Ctrl + J and seeing what happens.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to group several objects and then manipulate them (scale, rotate, translate) as one?](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/105/is-it-possible-to-group-several-objects-and-then-manipulate-them-scale-rotate)

Comment: I have no problems rotating/scaling/translating the group, i just don't know how to animate it rotating [GIF](http://imgur.com/o3BiQQA)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you rotate multiple selected objects and they all rotate about their own axis it is probable that your pivot point is set to 'Individual Origins'. This would mean exactly as you describe that each object selected will rotate about their own origin.

https://www.blender.org/manual/getting_started/basics/transformations/transform_control/pivot_point/index.html

If you don't really care about where they rotate about, you can just use the 'Median Point' as the pivot point, but if you want to make a precise rotation around a specific point, an easy way to do this would be creating an empty at the point of rotation and parenting all the objects you want to that empty. Then, you can simply rotate that empty and all of the parented objects will rotate around that empty. There are other ways to do this but from personal experience I think that if you are just doing a 2 key frame animation then using an empty as a center of rotation is one of easiest ways to rotate about a specific point.

Here is your .blend edited with the group parented to an empty cube and with the correct rotations.

[image]

Comment: Here this should explain my problem [GIF](http://imgur.com/o3BiQQA) keyframes created when whole group selected + rotated

Comment: Can you upload your .blend? I am not sure what is happening in the gif though I do see what you describe as your problem.

Comment: [Here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/kqh9zk7y43r1znz/CoronaRay1.blend?dl=0) should be the .blend file, let me know if you need the .blend1 file too.

Comment: I see what your problem is, but I have no idea why that is happening. If you parent the whole group to an empty cube object then the problem is solved. I edited my answer to include your .blend edited with the empty cube parenting.

Comment: Thanks! :D So parent parent instead of group? I think it's happening because of my computer; once i had to ctrlC+V the whole model in different file because i manged to break the visual scale/rotate feature-had to scale/rotate in object properties

Comment: @G_glop As it relates to .blend1 files, you could have a look at this - http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/23470/blend1-file-function#comment33837_23470