# Undo Functions on a single layer

Tags: workflow, layers

Is there a way to undo steps, including removing modifiers, similar to how one works through or deletes Photoshop layers?

Comment: Just to be sure I understand correctly, you want to undo everything you did (but only on one specific layer)?

Comment: Thanks for your interest. Yes, after completely painting myself into a corner, how do I step back out of the room, so to speak, one step at a time? Perhaps the answer lies in the outliner? Just using the PS layers as an analogy because I am a complete novice.

Comment: Blender's undo functionality is pretty limited, all you can really do is the usual Ctrl Z. It does have some lower level data recovery systems which may help you, see: http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/3026/599 and http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/14101/599