# Does Blender remember every manipulation done?

Tags: modeling, edit-mode

Does Blender remember every manipulation done (especially creating mesh, scaling, translation, rotation, extrusion, deletion, loop cut etc)? If not, how can this be achieved? Because I was looking at this video and was asking myself how every edit he made were recorded and I would like to look back the process of my model. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3edaWDU_xKE

Comment: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/3026/how-increase-decrease-undo-steps

This is probably what you're looking for

Comment: Yes, I've read this :D But I would like to know how to record the edits, because the person who modeled the car didn't make that car without breaks :P

Comment: There is an addon for creating snapshots from mesh - http://blenderaddonlist.blogspot.com/2015/03/addon-non-destructive-modelling.html, and possibility returning to them after if something's not good..

Comment: @MrZak Why not converting this into an answer?

Comment: @poor as I've got from Jerryno asnwer, the OP wanted to create animation using that and that it's not possible. And yes, that addon can't do that. So I was in doubt whether this answer could be useful for other visitors

Comment: @MrZak Ok, upvoted the comment - hopefully other users will find it...

Answer (score 3):

No it doesn't remember edits for playback like you want (and like ZBrush and others can).

What you would need to do is to export each step as an .obj, load them all into a new scene and animate them so they appear in a sequence one after another.

Then you can render this with orbiting camera and with wire-frame modifier on.

Using scripting to do this would be smart, there are many answers here how to import multiple obj's and how to animate multiple objects.

Some addons can store geometry states into a buffer, but there is no way that I know of how to efficiently animate them.