# Ctrl Z works separately in edit mode and text window. In object mode it affects both. Anyway to fix this?

Tags: interface

I'm programming a script that requires blender to be in object mode to see the results. I like to undo the results, modify the script and try again. When I CTRL Z to undo the results, it also undoes my script changes!
If I'm scripting something for edit mode, CTrL Z allows me to undo my mesh changes, but does not affect the script file. Any way I can change this behavior? What am I missing?

Comment: This is the intended behavior.

Comment: @someonewithpc, could you explain the reasons, please (I feel this very annoying too)?

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/35975/why-cant-i-get-my-undo-history-back

Answer (score 1):

If you press Ctrl + Z in object mode it undoes all of the changes you did when you were in edit mode at **once**(so be careful with that) **AND** all of the changes you did in object mode **individually**. When in edit mode it undoes all of the changes in edit mode **individually** but none of the changes in object mode. You can't change change it in the preferences. Dunno about console since I'm not a expert in Python.