# Undo isn't working correctly?

Tags: modeling

When I push undo it seems to go back too far? How can I set it to go one step at a time? I don't belive I changed any settings.

Comment: Related - http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/35975/why-cant-i-get-my-undo-history-back

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you are undoing in the edit mode. Undoing in the edit mode will undo individual steps you made while editing your object (eg. moving vertices, extruding faces...). Undoing in object mode will undo every change made to that object while you were in edit mode.